# How to set a schema from resources on a DOM "Document"

Tags: android, xsd, android-xml

I cant find anything about it.
I just want to find if a specific row exist in my DOM xml object (and more efficiently then going through all nodes).

In order to do that I need an ID attribute and in order to set an attribute as an ID so I could use getElementById I need to set a schema on my DocumentBuilderFactory.

So.. I built an XSD file in a pretty random spot in my resurces (folder called xml) - is there a standard place to put it in?

and I tried something like this:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("online_list_schema.xsd"));
    Schema mySchema;
    mySchema = factory.newSchema(schemaSource);

    dbf.setSchema(mySchema);
```

yes , I don't really know how to use getResourceAsStream .. (why does it asks for a Sting and not for Int?)

but lets start with the fact that

> SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

generates an error even if its by its own..

> 12-05 10:00:27.879: E/AndroidRuntime(996): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

so my questions are:

1. where should I put an xml schema in my resources (or- should I put
   xml schema in my resources if not what should I do?)
2. why does SchemaFactory.newInstance gives me an error and how do I
   use it correctly
3. how to load the schema source from my resources and are the other
   lines in the code correct?